# why there's bug if i use static variable in recursive function ? c++

Tags: c++, recursion, static, static-variables

**what am i trying to do is** write binary search tree insertion function...i know there are other ways to write this program...but i am curious about this function why doesn't it work?
my code is -

```
void insertionbst(struct node *root,int key){  
static struct node *n = newnode(key);
if(root->data!=key){
if(root == NULL){
    root = n;
}
else if(key < root->data){
    if(root->left == NULL){
        root->left = n;
        return;
    }
    else{
    insertionbst(root->left,key);
    }
}
else{
    if(root->right == NULL){
        root->right = n;
        return;
    }
    else{
    insertionbst(root->right,key);
    }
}
}
else{
    cout<<"element already exists"<<endl;
}

}
```

**Problem i am facing** - so in this code i made static variable *n because i dont want to make copies for every recursive layer but this static variable keeps same value even if i try to insert another key for example -

```
insertionbst(root,30);
insertionbst(root,35);
```

it doesn't insert key 35 in BST instead of 35 it keeps inserting 30

Thank You for Help

Comment: You already know that the value of `n` persists across multiple invocations of `insertionbst`. That's what you made it `static` _for_. So why are you surprised that the second time you call `insertionbst`, it's using the value of `n` from the first time you called it?

Comment: A static variable in a function/method is initialized only once.

Comment: The *purpose* of a `static` variable is that it is a single entity which is initialised exactly once (in the first call of your function) and has the same value everywhere (in your case, the same value in every recursive call).   So, if you don't want the same value everywhere, it should not be `static`.   Bear in mind that your code allocates using `new` but never does a corresponding `delete`.   So, whether it is `static` or not, you have a memory leak   (`static` only changes the nature of the leak in your code, not the fact there is a leak).

Comment: Try `static struct node *n; n = newnode(key);` i.e. keep it static but do the new each time through the function (this is of course based on what wohlstad pointed out).

Comment: Assuming `newnode` actually is doing some sort of `new` under the hood, wouldn't repeating this in every recursive call be a massive memory leak? I'd suggest considering some of the "other ways to write this program", like "don't construct the node until immediately before you place it into the tree" and "don't do this recursively at all"

Comment: thank you guys for the explanation i really appreciate that and Yunnosch that really worked....but how can i prevent memory leak because newnode(key) function is being invoked multiple times in every recursive layer

Comment: *but this static variable keeps same value even if i try to insert another key* That is exactly how static variables are supposed to work, and that is exactly the reason you should not be using a static variable here.

Comment: `if(root->data!=key){` is UB if `root` is `NULL`. (And stop writing C disguised as C++, use `nullptr`. `struct node` should just be `node`.). The compiler can then eliminate the following `if(root == NULL){` and on top the `root = n;` has 0 effect. You should be using `void insertionbst(node *&root,int key){`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm missing something, but why don't you just allocate the node when you need it?

```
void insertionbst(struct node *root,int key){  
    if(root->data!=key){
        if(root == NULL){
            root = newnode(key);
        }
        else if(key < root->data){
            if(root->left == NULL){
                root->left = newnode(key);
                return;
            }
            else{
                insertionbst(root->left,key);
            }
        }
        else{
            if(root->right == NULL){
                root->right = newnode(key);
                return;
            }
            else{
                insertionbst(root->right,key);
            }
        }
    }
    else{
        cout<<"element already exists"<<endl;
    }
}
```

I can't see any reason why you need to *make copies for every recursive layer*.

I think your code has bugs, it doesn't deal correctly with the situation when `root` equals `NULL`. Maybe that situation never arises in practice, in which case you still need to clean up the code.

Comment: Tangential: Would you need to change `insertionbst(root->left, key);` to `return insertionbst(root->left, key);` if you wanted to allow for tail call optimizations? Or is the compiler able to "see" that nothing else happens in `insertionbst` after the recursive call and perform that optimization automatically?

Comment: @NathanPierson Assuming that the compiler performs tail call optimisation I would expect that `return` is unnecessary. But if I was concerned about that I would code it as a loop in the first place.